# Using attr_encrypted with rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, attr-encrypted

We have upgraded our application to rails 7, and we are now having issues with the attr_encrypted gem. When we try start a rails server/console we get the following error:

```rb
gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/attr_encrypted-3.1.0/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:176:in `block in attr_encrypted': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If we revert back to rails 6 the error disappears, has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Rails 7 ships with built in encryption which obsoletes the gem. The latest update to the gem was 4 years ago. He's dead Jim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I have finally figured out what's going on.

Rails 7.0 has it's own encryption, both the attr_encrypted gem and rails 7 refer to the variable `encrypted_attributes` and the rails 7 variable takes precedence making the gem useless. There is a PR on the attr_encrypted gem to fix this but the gem has not been updated in years and I doubt it will be now.

GoRails published a tutorial on how to migrate your data from using attr_encrypted to using the rails 7 encryption. I did not want to pay for it so I checked out the git repo for the tutorial.

What they did is they decrypted the data themselves in a migration and updated the new encrypted fields manually.

Here is the link to their migration.
https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/migrate-attr_encrypted-to-rails-7-encryption/blob/master/db/migrate/20211005214633_migrate_encrypted_attributes.rb

Answer (score 2):

A [new version 4.0.0](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/releases/tag/v4.0.0) of the gem `attr_encrypted` was released on April 6 2023 and it comes with Rails 7 support.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. It actually saved me a ton of time and effort, since I didn't realize they released a new version to support Rails 7. I checked it back in March and there was no direction to support Rails 7.

Comment: Bump! Guys, just update the gem, it doesn't seem to have any breaking dependencies.

Comment: Also, don't forget to update all of the `encrypted_attributes[]` to `attr_encrypted_encrypted_attributes` to avoid runtime errors related to the upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Based on previous answer, a complete migration in both directions:

```
class SwitchToRailsBuiltInEncryption < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]

  ATTRIBUTES = [
    [Account, :password],
    [Account, :client_secret],
  ]

  def up
    ATTRIBUTES.each do |klass, attribute|
      klass.reset_column_information

      add_column klass.table_name, attribute, :string, length: 510

      klass.all.each do |record|
        puts "Processing #{klass} with ID #{record.id}"
        if record.send("encrypted_#{attribute}").present?
          encrypted_value = record.send("encrypted_#{attribute}")
          iv = record.send("encrypted_#{attribute}_iv")
          value = decrypt(encrypted_value, iv)
          record.update!(attribute => value)
        end
      end

      remove_column klass.table_name, "encrypted_#{attribute}"
      remove_column klass.table_name, "encrypted_#{attribute}_iv"
    end
  end

  def down
    ATTRIBUTES.each do |klass, attribute|
      add_column klass.table_name, "encrypted_#{attribute}", :string, length: 510
      add_column klass.table_name, "encrypted_#{attribute}_iv", :string, length: 510

      klass.all.each do |record|
        puts "Processing #{klass} with ID #{record.id}"
        if record.send(attribute).present?
          encrypted_value, iv = encrypt(record.send(attribute))
          record.update!("encrypted_#{attribute}" => encrypted_value, "encrypted_#{attribute}_iv" => iv)
        end
      end

      remove_column klass.table_name, attribute
    end
  end

  # based on https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/migrate-attr_encrypted-to-rails-7-encryption/blob/master/db/migrate/20211005214633_migrate_encrypted_attributes.rb
  # as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096672/using-attr-encrypted-with-rails-7
  def decrypt(encrypted_value, iv)
    value = Base64.decode64(encrypted_value)

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-gcm")
    cipher.decrypt

    cipher.key = Rails.application.credentials.key
    cipher.iv = Base64.decode64(iv)

    cipher.auth_tag = value[-16..]
    cipher.auth_data = ""

    cipher.update(value[0..-17]) + cipher.final
  end

  def encrypt(value)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-gcm")
    cipher.encrypt

    cipher.key = Rails.application.credentials.key
    iv = cipher.random_iv

    cipher.auth_data = ""

    encrypted_value = cipher.update(value) + cipher.final

    return Base64.encode64(encrypted_value + cipher.auth_tag), Base64.encode64(iv)
  end
end
```

Comment: The previous answer seems complete enough. This is just not necessary.